# Перенос строки в Telnet

Tags: linux, telnet

Обьясните, пожалуйста, особо одаренному, как в telnet сделать перевод строки? То есть я пишу
`telnet httpbin.org 80` --> enter
`GET / HTTP/1.1` --> и здесь при нажатии `enter`, `shift+enter`, `ctrl + enter`, `alt + enter`. Все что угодно + enter --> он выполняет команду а не делает перевод строки.
OS Linux

Comment: Непонятно о какой такой команде речь, в моём линуксе обычный enter делает обычный перенос строки без всяких команд

Comment: И у меня в телнете после строки GET первый enter ничего и не думает выполнять и можно писать спокойно заголовки. А после этого как и положено после двух переводов строки (и при отсутствии Content-length) начинается выполнение запроса

Comment: @andreymal как я понял ему нужно без сброса данных дописать команду.

Comment: Я бы неткат использовал `nc... << EOF..... `

Comment: Под командой имею ввиду то, что написано в строке (то есть сам запрос GET / HTTP/1.1). И при нажатии Enter - он не добавляет пустую строку а отправляет его сразу.

Answer (score 0):

telnet задумывался как удаленный шел-клиент (типа "удаленный баш"), поэтому Enter посылает введенный текст из клиента (телнет) на сервер для выполнения.

На enSO рекомендуют предварительно подготавливать текст в редакторе.

По идее, чтобы сначала отредактировать запрос, а потом отправить его на сервер, нужно включить специальный режим `mode character` или `mode line`, на enSO написано что это сработало на MAC.

```
telnet httpbin.org 80
Trying 3.220.112.94...
Connected to httpbin.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**^]** - это спецсимвол перевода клиента в режим управления. На моей клавиатуре нужно нажать `Ctrl + 5`. Тогда консоль сменит приглашение:

```
telnet>
```

Тут можно узнать разные параметры, введя `help`.

Теперь введем `mode line`:

```
telnet> mode line
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
...
```

И тут сервер закрыл соединение. То же самое - при `mode character`. Почему? Похоже, он не поддерживает эти режимы. Также я попробовал на другом типе веб-сервера, результат - тот же.

Резюме: похоже, что поддержка режима редактирования зависит от возможностей клиента и сервера. Если у вас не получилось, думайте про использование другой программы.

Ссылки:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4159386/9435985
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28190092/9435985